# Wordpress custom last posts PAGINATION

Tags: ajax, wordpress, pagination, ajaxify

I want to add pagination to my front page last posts but i keep failing..!
My code:

```
                    <?php
                        $recentPosts = new WP_Query();
                        $recentPosts->query('showposts=4&cat=3');
                    ?>
                <?php while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>
                    <div id="thepost">
                        <div class="view view-fifth">
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); endif; ?>
                        <div class="mask">
                            <h2>title</h2>
                            <p><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="posttitle"><a class="ajax" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                    <hr class="hr"/>
                    <p class="postcontent"><?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 42, 120);?>...&nbsp;<a class="ajax" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>">more...</a></p>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

I have ajaxify my "more..." button so i would like to do the same for the pagination :)
Sorry for my bad enlish ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `query_posts` insted of `Wp_Query`.

Some time pagination not working in `Wp_Query`.

Try this : 
1) http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts
2) http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links